# How do I get a complete PowerShell script trace output in VSCode?

Tags: powershell, trace, vscode-debugger

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I can't seem to find how to get a line by line trace of a PowerShell script running in the debugger of VS Code.

Using the ordinary PowerShell host console, I just enable tracing using.

`Set-SpDebug -Trace 1`

Tracing this simple script

```
function Write-Hello {
  Write-Verbose 'About to write Hello'
  Write-Host 'Hello'
}

Write-Hello
```

will generate the output

```
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> .\hello.ps1
DEBUG:    6+  >>>> Write-Hello
DEBUG:    1+ function Write-Hello  >>>> {

DEBUG:    2+    >>>> Write-Verbose 'About to write Hello'

DEBUG:    3+    >>>> Write-Host 'Hello'

Hello
DEBUG:    4+  >>>> }
```

Is there a way of achieving this generic tracing in VS Code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to simply use `Set-PSDebug` in the PowerShell Terminal of VSCode which will trace any script and module I run from within VSCode.

[image]